# Using lemmatizer to print the root of a word

Tags: python, nlp, pycharm, nltk

I'm using nltk for the first time, and I'm getting an error that I don't know how to troubleshoot any help is appreciated!

```
from nltk.stem import WordNetLemmatizer
import nltk


nltk.download('wordnet')
lemmatizer = WordNetLemmatizer()

x = 'was'
y = 'is'

lemma = lemmatizer.lemmatize(x, 'v')
print(lemma)  # Output: be
```

The error that I am getting is that the wordnet resource is not found. I am running in Pycharm and using python as the language.

````
**********************************************************************
  Resource wordnet not found.
  Please use the NLTK Downloader to obtain the resource:```
````

Answer (score 0):

Just Import the `WordNetLemmatizer` after downloading and before running the lemmatization:

```
from nltk import WordNetLemmatizer
```